# Merged commits appear as orphaned branches in Git Extensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

For one special repository I'm encountering a strange behavior in Git Extensions. Whenever I merge changes from a remote branch into my local branch, the merged commits appear in my branch and the merge appears as if I merged an orphaned branch.

The merge looks like:

[image: This is how the merge looks like.]

This is the beginning of my history:

[image: The beginning.]

In Visual Studio Team Explorer it looks more like I'd expect it to:

[image: This is what I'd expect.]

Furthermore, on my co-workers machine it looks pretty much the same in Git Extensions as it does on my machine in Visual Studio. It also looks right for other repositories on my machine.

I've already tried to

- Check out the repository again in another folder
- Reinstall GitExtensions
- Delete the folder and then check it out again
- Check Git Extensions settings

But I've not been able to overcome the issue. Is there anything I can do about it? Is there any Git cache I can delete in order to fix it? Any setting in Git Extensions?

Comment: A commit (a branch), whose parent commit is very far behind the current tip, is merged. At the bottom of these lines, there's expected to be a commit (the parent). If you don't like such history, you need to change your workflow.

Comment: @ElpieKay I do not know if I got you right, but - if you look at the visualization from Visual Studio - the commits are not that old when they get merged. The merge at the bottom of the first graph is the lower merge in the third graph. There are just two commits that get merged, short after they've been made. The first graph basically shows the same timespan as the third one does.

Comment: I can't see any refs (branch names) on the graph, but I don't think the refs in the first and second images are the same with the refs in the third image. If they are, some of the commits may be hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you happen to have "show first parents" turned on, it is known to break the graph this way. It's in the "View" menu.

Comment: @max630 : do you have a link to an issue on github about this problem?

Comment: @CyrilGandon It was shortly discussed [here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2351#issuecomment-306392949). There is no separated reported issue I would be aware of.

Comment: Thank you! From what I understand, i's more a feature of the `show first parents` than a bug.